# NX monorepo in a dotnet Angular project

Tags: c#, angular, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am doing some research for a new project. This project will use .NET/C# for the backend and now I am investigating about the best way to integrate the frontend in the same repository.

There will be multiple client apps like a web based CMS and Android/iOS mobile apps. Because of the team expertise NX, Angular and Ionic has been chosen as client technologies.

I know dotnet has a template to create an Angular SPA project, since there will be multiple client apps and we want to share code between them I wanted to convert it in an NX monorepo but beside [this](https://dkreider.medium.com/convert-your-net-core-with-angular-spa-app-to-an-nx-environment-quick-guide-664acef16040) article (not working for me) I didn't find how to do it. I came across [nx-dotnet](https://www.nx-dotnet.com/) but wraps a C# backend inside a native NX monorepo (I am trying to do the opposite: NX in a dotnet project).

Is there any tool or docs about converting the dotnet Angular template in a monorepo? What is a good practice to share code between multiple client apps in a dotnet solution?

I thought about the following alternatives:

- Init the NX monorepo in a folder and treat it like a normal node app (not a dotnet project)
- Use [Angular Workspace](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects) feature

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I am trying the same with a react+dotnet monorepo and couldn't find any good documentation

Comment: Hello, not really. In the end we started with just a .Net Angular project. Now we are resuming the topic because we have to start another frontend project in the same solution.

Comment: @Max so a member of my team did some exploration about it. Our best shot is to create an empty class library that will be used as file container with a `tsconfig.json` to include all the project files. In another .Net/Angular project we extend that `tsconfig.json` so Angular/TypeScript can import the files in the project. Still have to try but for the moment is the best solution we can think.

Comment: A related question that's helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66359136/8644294